# Pseudo-synchronous programming in Javascript, but is there a better implementation?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a prototype of JavaScript coding lessons for young children (8-10 years), which is based on animation. The teaching  script allows its users to program synchronously, like

```
draw(something);
wait(some time); 
draw(something_else);
```

Synchronous programming appears much friendlier than the regular JavaScript technique, but behind the scene is async/await, and it's not bogging down the browser.

You can try how it works at http://codepegs.com/ and find the explanation at http://codepegs.com/cphelp.html (scroll to **The timed functions**).

The async/await is very restraining. Much more can be done, but before refactoring the system let me ask if you know of an existing solution for pseudo-synchronous programming in JavaScript, which I could use?

I tried to search, and the answers were like no way. That's why I linked an example.

PS: Sorry, I have to add a post scriptum. I asked to suggest a more elaborate implementation. In principle, it was done a year ago. It was crude, but it works. I don't like it for many reasons, but I decided to ask before embarking on a new bout of programing.

Look, after the script (or spell) have finished running (asynchronously), it leaves behind the sequence of functions to be executed on time, this way or another. Many things can be done with such a list. Suppose you want to cancel some pending  functions, or you want to repeat them, maybe changing something, etc. This pseudo-synchronous model is not horribly complicated, but it's not this simple. Imagine you want an infinite animation (this was implemented, but in a clumsy way), etc.

Comment: Why not just use Promises or a named variant of such?

Comment: `The async/await is very restraining.`  What does this mean?

Comment: I didn't really get from that web page how it works. Are the "spells" parsed and interpreted? Are they transpiled to javascript that uses `async`/`await`? Are they executed as JS directly, their outputs recorded, and only the visualisation is deferred?

Comment: Transpiling is something most Javascript developers do, a popular one is Babel,.  And someone has even created a plugin to do what I believe your after.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-auto-await   One gotcha,  awaiting a none promise doesn't cause problems, but can cause a slight performance issue.  But even this could be rectified, by maybe altering this plugin to only auto-await certain function names, like  `draw` and `wait` etc.

Comment: To Bergi: spells are JavaScript. It's just a "funny" name. Just read the first chapter. Unfortunately, only the visualization was deferred, and this is not right.

Comment: To Keith: yes, Babel. Thank you.  But it's not exactly what I want. I added a PS. Async/await: at the time of the development, I could not even cancel it. SetTimeout would be better.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by Bergi it might be more elegant to actually run the code in a synchronous manner and push all the changes into a queue, then you can replay the changes slowly:

```
  const queue = [];

  function draw(text) { queue.push({command: "draw", value: text }); }
  function wait(value) { queue.push({ command: "delay", value }); }

  async function end() {
    for(const { command, value } of queue) {
       switch(command) {
          case "draw":
            console.log(value);
            break;
         case "delay":
            await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, value));
            break;
      }
   }
}

// Your code:
draw("And you get...");
wait(1000);
draw("nothing :/");
end();
```

Comment: That's how I did it. Transpiling - well, it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable way to do I/O in front-end JS synchronously. There is synchronous AJAX, but WebWorkers, setTimeout, WebSockets etc, are always async.

So you will need `async/await` to get synchronous-style coding patterns.

There is one other way, you basically create a promise queue:

```
enqueue(function foo(){}); // put on the queue
enqueue(function bar(){}); // put on the queue
enqueue(function baz(){}); // put on the queue
```

what this means is that foo, bar and baz will be run in order, if the queue only processes one function call at a time. But there is no easy way to pass the result of one function to the next, without a library involved. That's what promises or the async library is for.

To see how the queue methodology works, check out this library:

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#usage

Answer (score 0):

In case everything else fails, you could still write your own JavaScript transpiler in JavaScript itself:

You could either make your code promising, then just transpile the program to use async / await:

```
  function execute(context, code) {
    let result = "";
    for(const line of code.split("\n"))) {
      if(["if", "else", "var", "for", "while"].some(keyword => line.includes(keyword)) {
        result += line + "\n";
      } else {
        result += "await " + line + "\n";
      }
    }
    with(context) { 
       return eval(`(async function() { ${result} })()`);
     }
  }
```

Then just pass the users code to the execution:

```
  execute({
    async draw() { /*...*/ },
    async wait(ms) { await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)); },
  },
  `draw(something);
   wait(some time); 
   draw(something_else);`
 );
```

Thats just to give you a basic idea, but [it works quite well](https://jsbin.com/pagayikine/edit?console).

---

Or another approach could be to build up an iterator that allows you to through the code line by line:

```
  let continuation = Promise.resolve();

  function wait(ms) { continuation = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }
  function draw() { /*...*/ }

   function execute( code) {
     const iterator = eval("(function* () {" + code.split("\n").join("\nyield;\n") + "})();");
    function next() {
      const { value, done } = iterator.next();
      if(done) return;
      continuation.then(next);
    }
 }

  execute(`
    console.log("wait a second....");
    wait(1000);
    console.log("done!");
 `);
```

That also [works](https://jsbin.com/wokuvowutu/edit?console) and I guess it is actually quite a good workaroumd, it will only fail if the code contains multiline strings / functions.

Comment: Not sure of the down-vote here, anonymous downvoter out tonight.. :0   My idea was something similar, maybe use babel and a custom plugin to do this.

Comment: @keith babel will probably be the more elegant solution in the long term.

Comment: Looks like the OP, might not even need to write his own plugin, just found this -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-auto-await